# Attiny85 reprogramming without unplugging and replugging the USB cable

Tags: bootloader, attiny85

Is it possible to reprogram this version of Attiny85 without needing to unplug the USB cable?

The board version below is running micronucleus bootloader and has the REST pin enabled. But resetting the board does not send it into bootloader. You have to unplug and replug it into USB to enter the bootloader so you can upload an updated version.

Apparently Trinket from Adafruit did support that with a different bootloader.

What other bootloaders can be installed on this hardware below and do anyone of them support resetting via a button and reprogramming?

[image: Attiny from Aliexpress or ebay]
[image]

I want to use this for teaching kids programming and it is big disadvantage if they have to replug USB constantly. If not I will have to use Esp8266 instead.

Comment: Technically the Trinket bootloader should run here, I just don't know if it is freeware. Do you have a schematic of this device?

Comment: That's not a "version of ATTiny85", that's a random cheap device/board with a ATTiny85 microcontroller. How it works depends on the design. But as these don't really have USB, it uses the same principle of bit-bashing 3.3V USB pins via 5V GPIO pins and Zener limiting, which is a poor kludge to make an USB interface. Please be aware that there is an increased risk of damaging computer USB ports with this. Just to be sure you know this if they are school owned or student owned computers.

Comment: ok. I added the schematics for it. I am not too worries about the PC being damaged. I can always use a USB hub in between. I wonder if there is a way to send the program into bootloader once it has entered the user program space. I doubt there is any protection between the bootloader and user program in the micronucleus. The schematics for trinket are different. I have not really compared them but know that they have managed to get the reset working with a different bootloader.